# Subsonic generate table without primary key

Tags: subsonic

I need to generate a table without primary key. Its absolutely neccessary that the table dosen't have primary key. Please help.

Comment: what version of subsonic are you using? are you using repository or activerecord?

Comment: But the problem is that a lot of data is repeated and cannot be made primary key. Is there any other solution

Comment: You can always add a ID column that is auto generated and has no relation to your data, there shouldn be much overhead but this will allow you to generate your datalayer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there any reason you cannot use something like sequences?

```
class Something {
     private static final SEQUENCE seq = getDBsequence()

     @id
     private final long id = seq.newNumber();

     private final String whateverData;
}
```

EDIT:The way I wrote this was kinda dumb because once you reboot the app. you'll get duplicate keys.. You should use a sequence provided by the DB. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 5):

It is absolutely necessary for the SubSonic that table contains primary key:)

The following is quoted from the [SubSonic docs on conventions](http://www.subsonicproject.com/docs/Conventions):

> Primary Keys
>
> If you want to use SubSonic to access your table, you need to have a Primary Key defined for your table. This is good practice in every case and we need it to do certain things with your table. If you don't have a Primary Key defined, your class won't be generated.
>
> If you don't believe us, or if you think this is a silly convention - SubSonic isn't for you.

Comment: But the problem is that a lot of data is repeated and cannot be made primary key. Is there any other solution

Comment: simple just add another identity column and don't use it in your application logic but Subsonic needs this to distinguish the records.

Comment: oh, @stalkerh has also suggested this in his comment!

Answer (score 1):

as Adam pointed out this isn't possible. To be honest I can't think of a situation (outside OLAP) where you can't have a PK. Or perhaps you're stuck in a legacy situation - I can dig that.

What you can do to get around it is, as you pointed out, use our querier tools and then you can send the results ToList<>. Updates should work the same way - not sure about inserts though.